# SQL ALTER TABLE Excluding a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, alter-table

I have a MySQL table named '`leaderboard`' and it has 5 columns `'name','regno','dept','gpa','rank'` I have set rank to `AUTO_INCREMENT` and now I want to order the table by '`gpa`', but rank of the row should not change. The table should be sorted permanently not just printing output.

For example:-

```
regno name dept gpa rank                 
1      a    c    8   1        
2      b    d    9   2
```

After sorting the table should be like this:-

```
regno name dept gpa rank   
2      b    d    9   1   
1      a    c    8   2
```

See the rank column is not changed.

Comment: `The table should be sorted permanently not just printing output` That's not how usually databases work provided the tables are defined already

Comment: Enlarging upon what @Hanky웃Panky wrote, if you issue a SELECT statement to a table without an explicit ORDER BY, the order of the rows in the result set is formally unpredictable. If you depend on any particular order in your software, that software contains a latent bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than storing the Rank in your table and selecting it out try to calculate it on the fly. Try something like the following:

```
SELECT    regno, 
          name, 
          dept, 
          gpa
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      leaderboard, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  gpa;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get that or you can get that! 
Because what you see is a logical representation of you bytes stored in a database, so it's all a representation! 
What  you can do is create a view for you with a specific sort order on that `gpa` column ! 
What do you think about that ?

**Just to make a point :  - i am copying @SARIN**

```
create view Oreder_data_like_i_want_to_see_it 
 as 
SELECT    regno, 
          name, 
          dept, 
          gpa
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      leaderboard, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  gpa;
```

Comment: Why don't you check @sarin answer. :)

Comment: He is creating a view of your data !

Comment: Well I am trying to bridge my android app with the database. So in my PHP file i modified it to take the values from the view and not from the table as it is and it is working.